# What is the purpose of "extends boolean" in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Could someone help me improve my understanding of "conditional types". In the documentation for Typescript, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types they have the following example:

> ```
> declare function f<T extends boolean>(x: T): T extends true ? string : number;
>
> // Type is 'string | number'
> let x = f(Math.random() < 0.5)
> ```

What I don't understand is, why is it necessary to write it that way. Wouldn't the following suffice?

> ```
> declare function f(x : boolean): T extends true ? string : number;
> ```

Comment: because the latter has no generic type parameter `T`?  If you're replacing `T` with `boolean` you need to replace it everywhere (and be careful with [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) conditionals) and you'd end up with `declare function f(x: boolean): string | number`.  Which is fine but it wouldn't represent that `f(true)` returns `string` and `f(false)` returns `number`.

Comment: To reproduce that without a generic function returning a conditional type, you'd need an overloaded function with three call signatures [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIB4AVeEADwxFWAGd4AjHHCEKVAPgAoyAueIgJR8S5StToYYyBAH54NSVlQBzeH1TIAtvRAwA3ACgWGeGXgBeJJwCyUDAAsAdDDbAcmzgPgF4ABkcArAJ68AD0ofKKKvAAPvAa2rpGICYAnhZWktLBYREKMErKySYAXhmInIhQEDQgOeHxWjowBgagkLAIKOjYePDK3HxZdXz5hYbt0HBIaJi4+AO8SNW1Qo2J+m3gU12zvQuDDEwsbGtj0XEJzYbGpgBMGQO2Ds6u7p7efoH1eVGql00krdUg9LANhj9IgUVMV4CVQf1Kis6iEGlckq0gA). Does that explain it for you? I will write it up if so.

Comment: Thanks, your write up is helpful. But did you mean to write `let x2 = g(Math.random() < 5)`? I don't see `g(...)` being used anywhere.

Comment: I had hoped to edit that before you noticed, sorry.  Check again

Comment: I read your first comment over and over and I think I kind of understand now. Basically the function `f` takes something that is a boolean, and depending on what type of boolean it is (true or false), the return type is different. But how about this question -- why do I have to say `T extends boolean` ? Why can't I just say `T is a boolean`? Or is just that not possible...

Comment: `T extends boolean` is the syntax for [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).  The `extends` keyword implies that `T` could be `boolean` *or any subtype of* `boolean`.  Presumably that's what you mean by `T is a boolean`; if not, could you spell out the difference?  Is there enough here for me to write up an answer you'd be happy with?  Or do you have any outstanding questions?